# Работа с ADOQuery и DBComboBox

Tags: база-данных, delphi-7

В общем, ситуация следующая. Дали программу на переработку, и встала такая проблема. В оригинале программа отображает ФИО, из базы Access в DBEdit, и там запрос работает на выборку из ADOQuery. Я решил переделать и заместо DBEdit поставил DBComboBox, потому что изменил базу данных, и у меня стало больше, чем 1 человек там, а DBComboBox для удобства выбора. НО тут появилась ошибка: "ADOQuery1: Missing SQL property", и что делать, не знаю, ведь особо-то ничего не меняется, но DBComboBox отказывается работать, когда DBEdit, все отображает.

Скрины прилагаю:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ZverDVD, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть совет вам большой, бился не так давно с похожей проблемой. DBComboBox не совсем то, что хочется. Короче, мне нужно было сделать форму, на форме было поле для ввода гражданства, и еще поля ввода для Имени и Отчества. Важный момент, что при занесении имени и отчества они проверялись на то, что есть уже в справочнике или нет. При этом хотелось красивый выпадающий список с вариантами. Пробовал DBComboBox, потратил несколько дней, да только толку никакого. Он не умеет отображать динамически список из базы. Да еще и редактирует его. Он просто показывает первое значение указанного поля и все. В итоге я все переделал на связку ListBox - для отображения вариантов выбора, и просто Edit для ввода. Все получилось красиво и работает безотказно. Варианты берутся из справочника в базе. Решение [проблемы с DBComboBox](http://myshinobi.ru/problema-s-dbcombobox-vy-padayushhij-spisok-formiruemy-j-iz-bazy-danny-h/). По ссылке есть статья, там подробно все разобрал. Надеюсь, я вам помог.